# How to /setblock a specific type of redstone (Debug mode)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I've had a look at the new hidden world type on 1.8, and I've just wondered how to get a type of redstone that goes up in the north part of the square, and I want to use the `/setblock` command to create this without the appropriate blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:redstone_wire 0 replace {north:"none",south:"none",east:"none",west:"none",power:0}
```

Switch the none out for what you want:

none - no connection in that direction
side - goes horizontally in that direction
up - diagonally upward in that direction

in your case switch the north none with up.

Answer (score 1):

@ModDL gave a great answer, but sadly on my Minecraft 1.8, when I tried that using blockdata, it didn't do anything. I still appreciate his answer, although.

Check out the answers at [How to place redstone using Command Blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220594/how-to-place-redstone-using-command-blocks/).

Even when I first examined it using F3 on my Minecraft in 1.8, it showed it like this:

```
north:none
south:none
etc.
```

I tried modification using `/blockdata` but that didn't work.

So then I thought: Hmm... what about data values?

So then I tried `/setblock (x) (y) (z) redstone_wire (0-15)` and then like a miracle, it worked!

It turns out Minecraft is showing what the damage value corresponds to.

In 1.8+ it interprets the damage value so that it's human-readable.

*But* in 1.7 and lower, it just shows `(block name)/(damage value)`.