# How to place redstone using Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I used this to place redstone:

```
/setblock -624.5 244 -1692.5 redstone 0 replace
```

It gives an error saying that there is no such thing as `minecraft:redstone`. I tried many different things and nothing works. How can I make a command block place redstone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to /setblock a specific type of redstone (Debug mode)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189895/how-to-setblock-a-specific-type-of-redstone-debug-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are two reasons why this command probably isn't working:

- First, you can't have decimals with the co-ordinates of this particular Minecraft block. They have to be whole numbers not decimals. Try placing a block where you want the redstone to be, look at it, press <kbd>F3</kbd>. You will see the co-ordinates of the block in the top right hand side. (See 'looking at'). Destroy the block and use these co-ords in the command.
- Secondly, the id for redstone dust (the block) is `minecraft:redstone_wire`, as the inventory item is `minecraft:redstone`

Comment: Great! But decimals don't do anything except for reducing the tick delay (this also helps with ghost blocks) and that was not the error I was talking about. Thanks though.

Comment: If it helped, click the grey tick below the votes. Thankyou!

Comment: I couldn't for 10 minutes. Also, it's not an dumb question, why did you downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. That was someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Angus' answer, there are also 16 different states for redstone wire, which you can specify using the data value.

This is because: 2^4 = 16-1 = **0 to 15**.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting in:

```
/setblock -624.5 244 -1692.5 minecraft:redstone_block 0 replace
```

It worked for me.